# npm / node automate directory structure creation?

Tags: node.js, automation, directory-structure

I have googled this and nothing seems to be what I am looking for.
I tried bower, yeoman etc...

So I have a directory structure that I use frequently
How can I automate this?

- PROJECT FOLDER
- \app
- \app\assets\
- \app\assets\css
- \app\assets\fonts
- \app\assets\img
- \app\assets\js
- \compile\
- \compile\js
- \compile\js\vendor
- compile\scss\
- compile\scss... several folders here

Comment: Grunt/gulp with shell command (mkdir -p `directory`)?

Comment: would that allow me to create a "macro" so to speak.

Comment: You can create simple module and then use it globally with array of dirs for  every project or something like this (`bootstrap([dirs])`). Usually directory structure is creating by application itself (like Sails or similar) so the are no universal solution as I think.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this

http://joakim.beng.se/blog/posts/slush-replacing-yeoman-with-gulp.html

and then get slush from https://www.npmjs.com/package/slush

You can then easily create your own generator for your own structure.

There is a fairly good example of slush generator for angular that I used as a guide for mine

https://github.com/slushjs/slush-angular

Answer (score 0):

Grunt has the `grunt-mkdir` plugin. I'm not exactly sure what you're looking for though.

Using that, you can create a configuration for the folders you need:

```
makeDirectories: {
    options: {
        mode: 0700,
        create: ['reports', 'reports/coverage']
    }
}
```

And then use grunt to make them:

```
grunt mkdir:makeDirectories
```